# sinon.js verify mock method's arguments with callback

Tags: javascript, sinon

Is it possible to verify arguments with a callback. I'm thinking something like this:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(someObject, "method");

//json is an object with like 10 properties
spy.withArgs(function(json){
  return 'undefined' !== typeof json.importantProp1 && 'undefined' !== typeof json.importantProp2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with a callback. In order to verify arguments you can use `spy.calledWith` and similar.

http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies-api

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with a matcher:

```
spy.calledWithMatch(function(json){
  return 'undefined' !== typeof json.importantProp1
    && 'undefined' !== typeof json.importantProp2;
});
```

It is also possible to create a matcher with `sinon.match(function () {}))` and use it with `spy.withArgs`.

Comment: Is this also possible with mocks?

Comment: Should be, since mocks are constructed using stubs.